# Asp.Net: Create custom CheckBoxList using the ListView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Using VS 2019, c# 4.8 and Asp.net Webforms, I want to create a CheckBoxList using the ListView control.

I would like it to look something like this:
[image]

To start with, I created a class for the databinding:

```
public class Category
{
    public Guid CatId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

This is the html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="divStyle">
            <asp:ListView ID="CategoryCheckList" runat="server" class="CListStyle"
                GroupItemCount="3" ItemPlaceholderID="itemsGoHere"
                GroupPlaceholderID="groupsGoHere">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupsGoHere"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <GroupTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemsGoHere"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </tr>
                </GroupTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%--<td class="CListStyle"><%#Eval("CategoryName")%></td>--%>
                    <td><asp:CheckBox id="itemCheckBox" runat="server" /></td>
                    <asp:Label  ID="itemCheckBoxLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName")%>'></asp:Label>   
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>           
        </div>        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the codebehind:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private List<Category> _categories;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadCategories();
    }

    void LoadCategories()
    {
        List<Category> list = new List<Category>();
        list.Add(new Category { CatId = new Guid(), CategoryName = "xxxx" });
        list.Add(new Category { CatId = new Guid(), CategoryName = "xxxx" });
        list.Add(new Category { CatId = new Guid(), CategoryName = "xxxx" });
        list.Add(new Category { CatId = new Guid(), CategoryName = "xxxx" });
        list.Add(new Category { CatId = new Guid(), CategoryName = "xxxx" });
        list.Add(new Category { CatId = new Guid(), CategoryName = "xxxx" });
        list.Add(new Category { CatId = new Guid(), CategoryName = "xxxx" });
        list.Add(new Category { CatId = new Guid(), CategoryName = "xxxx" });
        _categories = list;
        CategoryCheckList.DataSource = _categories;
        CategoryCheckList.DataBind();
    }

    public List<Category> Categories { get => _categories; set => _categories = value; }
}
```

and when I run it, this is what it looks like:

[image]

1. What do I need to do to get this to look right, where the labels are beside the checkboxes?
2. What do I bind the CatId to?  When we do a postback, we need to loop through the list and get the Guid Ids of the items checked.

Thank you.

Comment: do you want one check box per row? Or is the choice exclusive (you check/choose one on the given row - the others then un-check - eg "one" choice per row? While you answering this - probably much better to use a data table here - since THEN you have defined column names - and you can then speicty the text display value for the check box, but also have a "value" for the choice.

Comment: This is a dynamic list.  I have a list of items where each item is represented as a checkbox.  I can have zero to many items and I have enough space for 3 columns of checkboxes and labels in the list.  So a data table would not work nicely and formatting columns would be problem.